# Help in field calculator expression editor hidden

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

I don´t have in field calculator "selected function help".

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @majus251! If you place your mouse cursor to the right of the scrollbar where the functions are, you can change the size of the window. Drag it to the left, this should open up the help window. I know this question was asked before but can't find it...

Answer (score 10):

It's just hidden away on the right side of the function list and you can expand it like this:

[image]