# Geometry generator & get_feature

Tags: qgis, style, geometry-generator

I am just trying to follow Anita Graser's examples in https://anitagraser.com/2017/04/08/a-guide-to-geometry-generator-symbol-layers/ - where the "Creating a line between features in different layers" part caught my attention.

Is there a way to select more than one feature based on an adequate function using wildcards or expressions for numerical fields ... like `ReturnAnyFeatrue('from_layer', 'with_field', >= 200)` ?

*get_feature*  just returns the first element that matches the "attribute"/"value" settings - thus the following expression returns a set of lines from any object of the current layer to a specific STATION - i.e. 'Millennium Tower':

```
make_line(  
centroid( $geometry ),  
geometry( get_feature( 'Citybike', 'STATION', 'Millennium Tower' ) )  
)
```

I am interestet in a way to draw geometry-generator-lines from current layers' points to any station starting with - for instance - "Mi" based on an expression like 'Mi*'
is there a way that just makes use of geometry generator and simple expression ?

(unfortunately, there is still a lack of documentation and examples concerning geometry generator ... )

Comment: ... just an additional note: i didn't find a documentaion of the geometry-related functions which are listed in the "Geometry"section of the "Expression string builder"-window. in particular i am looking for a comprehensive parameter desciption ... any ideas where to find it ??

Comment: Did u see the integrated help in the right part of this panel ? Could surely be more detailed but ... there's something ...

Comment: in know - there used to ba an integrated help. was desperately searching for that, but any of the "expression editor - windows" do not show that part of the window. and i have no idea where i have lost that part ... painful it is !

Comment: @roberttuw I think you can get only one feature per time using the built-in expressions. Instead, you may recur to a custom function for getting whatever you want. I can try to help you if you are add more information and context to your issue.

Comment: @mgri - thx for support. i've just posted a refined question which reflects that.

Comment: @ mgri - semi-off-topic: do you eventually have any idea how i can "turn on" that help section again ? ... it is definitely not visible in any of the "expression editor" dialogs

Comment: For the help, see [Help in field calculator expression editor hidden](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/237445/help-in-field-calculator-expression-editor-hidden/245894#245894)

Comment: @underdark: thx !

Comment: count me in as curious as well, I've been trying to work this out myself - I tried playing around with the new collect() function in QGIS 3 but this results in a multipoint geometry and the centroid only connects to the first of those.

Comment: See this answer here, that might work for you as well: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/381819/88814

Comment: thx to #babel - valuable hint !